# Get a class inside a clicked class in Javascript-Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I need to get a class item inside another clicked class item. How can I do that?
The class is being used by other items, so I can't use the document.getElementsByClassName method, because I only need that precise item I clicked. The pseudocode would be like this.

```
$(".class1").click(function ()
{
    var text = theclickeditem.getclass(".innerClass").innerText;
});
```

The innerClass is unique inside the class1

Comment: `var text = $(this).find('.innerClass').text();`. I'd suggest you read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com), as most of the method names, such as the ones used here, are self-explanatory

Comment: You read the jQuery documentation?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you very much, you've been very helpful (and fast)